# Dúvida SQL string_agg (Delphi+Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, delphi

Boa noite. Essa sql estava rodando exatamente como eu queria, mas ontem começou a ficar fora da ordem do campo  **g.galeria**. Tinha uma saída (exemplo) assim: **GALERIA 10: 26 / GALERIA 11: 23 / GALERIA 12: 21** e assim por diante. Agora sai totalmente fora da ordem, não entendi. Alguém enxerga o erro?

```
WITH quantidade as(
    Select g.galeria, g.tipo, g.finalidade, count(p.galeria) as total
    from presos p
    full join galerias g
    on p.galeria = g.galeria
    group by g.galeria,g.tipo,g.finalidade
    order by g.galeria
) 
Select string_agg(cast(g.tipo as text) || ' ' || cast(g.galeria as text) || ': ' || q.total, '  /  ') 
from galerias g full join quantidade q on (q.galeria = g.galeria and q.tipo = g.tipo and q.finalidade = g.finalidade)
WHERE g.galeria <= 50
```

Comment: Veja se incluir o `order by g.galeria` após `WHERE g.galeria <= 50` resolve. Ficaria: `WHERE g.galeria <= 50 order by g.galeria`. Talvez tivesse apagado por engano ou a ordenação poderia está configurada em algum componente do Delphi que você tenha substituído e não tenha configurado novamente. Faz um teste e dê um feedback.

Comment: Salve Clarck...já havia tentado isso...não rolou...

Comment: O problema pode ser devido à utilização no `WITH quantidade as` ... está usando `order by g.galeria` e no comando `Select string_agg(cast(g.tipo as text)` é iniciado com `g.tipo`. Veja a simulação realizada no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/359ce/1). Para melhorar o entendimento, sugiro que simule sua situação em outro ambiente semelhante ao que fiz no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/359ce/1).